# Get element type from templated container type

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm trying to write a template function that takes an arbitrary container class with an arbitrary numeric type:

```
template <typename NumType, typename ContType>
double avg_nums(const ContType<NumType> & data)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for(ContType::const_iterator iter = data.cbegin(); iter != data.cend(); ++iter)
    {
        if(typeid(NumType) == typeid(char) || typeid(NumType) == typeid(unsigned char))
        {
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(*iter) << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << *iter << " ";
        }

        sum += *iter;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return sum  / data.size();
}
```

but this gives a syntax error (VS2012). This doesn't work either:

```
template <typename NumType, typename ContType<NumType> >
double avg_nums(ContType<NumType> & data)
```

I want the type of object in the container to be a template parameter as well as the container type so I can add check for a specific cases of NumType. If I change the function signature to

```
template <typename NumType, typename ContType>
double avg_nums(ContType & data)
```

it builds but now it relies on explicitly specifying the correct template parameter:

```
std::vector<char> cvec = boost::assign::list_of(0) (1) (1) (2) (3) (5);
std::vector<int> ivec = boost::assign::list_of(0) (1) (1) (2) (3) (5);

avg_nums<char, std::vector<char>>(cvec);
avg_nums<int, std::vector<int>>(ivec);
```

If I change the signature to

```
template <typename ContType>
double avg_nums(ContType & data)
```

It works but now I don't have direct access to the element type. Can I get the element type from the type of the container (`std::vector<int>` or `std::list<unsigned char>`)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this form:

```
template <typename ContType>
double avg_nums(ContType & data)
```

and then get the element type as

```
typename ContType::value_type
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename ContType>
double avg_nums(ContType & data)
```

> It works but now I don't have direct access to the element type. Can I get the element type from the type of the container (std::vector or std::list)?

You can extract the type of the contained elements in standard containers by means of the nested type: `value_type`:

```
typedef typename ContType::value_type NumType;
```

I don't think I would implement that function anyway, since you can use existing algorithms that are well tested:

```
int value = 0;
int total = std::accumulate(container.begin(), container.end(), value);
double avg = total * 1. / container.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following template specialization variant might also be interesting if the container type doesn't feature some kind of 'value_type' (which is to be preferred way, because this one relies on the value type being the first template parameter which is not necessarily true):

```
    // define some custom container where we do not have some kind of 'value_type'
    template <typename... T> class CustomContainer {};

    // forward declare the template function so we can deduce the type in a specialization
    template <typename ContType> double avg_nums(ContType&);

    // specialization that deduces ContType and NumType from a single template argument
    // This works for all continers where the first template argument is the 'value_type'
    // also note the Ts... which is a placeholder for possible other template arguments that need to be passed on
    template <template <typename...> class ContType, typename NumType, typename... Ts>
    double avg_nums(ContType<NumType, Ts...>&)
    {
        // so the work
        return NumType(0);
    }

    int main(int,char**)
    {
        CustomContainer<int> cont;
        avg_nums(cont);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific current problem you can replace

```
template <typename NumType, typename ContType>
double avg_nums(const ContType<NumType> & data)
{
```

with

```
template< class ContType >
double avg_nums(ContType const& data)
{
    using NumType = typename ContType::value_type;
```

You will need a `typename` for the type specification in the loop head.

---

More generally you can do

```
template< template< class, class > class ContType_, class NumType, class Allocator >
double avg_nums(ContType_<NumType, Allocator> const& data)
{
    using ContType = ContType_<NumType, Allocator>;
```

---

And instead of

```
    if(typeid(NumType) == typeid(char) || typeid(NumType) == typeid(unsigned char))
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(*iter) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }
```

you can just use implicit promotion and write

```
    std::cout << +*iter << " ";
```

or perhaps `0+*iter` if you find that more clear.

---

In passing, do consider using `std::accumulate`.

---

Also, in passing, do think about how to handle an empty container.

---

Finally, instead of the explicit iterator usage you can just use a C++11 range-based `for`.